# Llenar un listview con una API

Tags: android, mysql, arraylist, android-listview, parsear

He estado intentando llenar una ListView con una consulta de MYSQL pero no tengo ningún resultado favorable, quiero implementar el uso de adapter y asignar en la listview únicamente el Nombre y Apellidos por cada elemento pero cuando intento asignar mi colección de datos me aparece el siguiente error:

**"No se puede convertir de  'System.Collections.ArrayList' a 'int' "**

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
async void CargarMaestros()
        {
             List<Maestro> _maestros;
             ListView _lvwMaestros;
             _maestros = await ClienteMaestros.ObtenerTodas();
             ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < _maestros.Count; i++)
                   {
                      items.Add(_maestros[i].Nombre + "" + _maestros[i].Apellidos);
                   }
              var adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);

              _lvwMaestros.Adapter = adaptador;
      }
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

```
    using System.Linq; //HACES USO DE LINQ

    async void CargarMaestros()
    {

       _maestros = await ClienteMaestros.ObtenerTodas();

      var itemsLista = _maestros.Select(m => $"{m.Nombre} \t {m.Apellidos}") .ToArray();

      var adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, itemsLista);

      _lvwMaestros.Adapter = adaptador;
   }
```

*SALUDOS :)*

Comment: Pudiste resolver tu problema?

Comment: Claro que sí y perdón por la demora, resulta que implementé lo siguiente (ADJUNTO LA SOLUCIÓN EN EL POST)

Answer (score 0):

El problema está, en que estás declarando el `ArrayList` de manera errónea, necesitas especificar el tipo de creación en su parámetro genérico.

Haces esto:

```
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
```

En vez de hacer esto:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
```

Otra cosa es que estas solo cambiando la referencia de una lista, no cambiando sus valores.

Haces esto:

```
_maestros = await ClienteMaestros.ObtenerTodas();
```

En vez de hacer esto:

```
_maestros.AddRange(await ClienteMaestros.ObtenerTodas());
```

Como resultado tendrías 2 referencias apuntando a una misma colección. Sin embargo con `AddRange` estas creando una copia de una colección (agregando los datos de una lista a otra lista). En tu caso no vas a notar la diferencia porque son variables locales. Pero debes tener pendiente eso para evitar futuros problemas con listas.